# postgis with ruby on rails query multipolygon

Tags: android, json, postgresql, postgis, arrays

If i make a query on my postgis database to get my districts, i get the following returned for my LatLon column:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText(latlon) AS geom FROM district;

MULTIPOLYGON(((16.4747103091463 48.2753153528078,16.4744319731163 48.275314069121,16.4743511374383 48.2753128173411,16.4743147576862 48.2753108825757,16.474247514683 48.275304398381,16.474205201686 48.2753004022899)))
```

But how am i supposed to work with this in my java android app?

The structure seems not to be correct.. Because if i want to start working with it.. i first have to cut out the parentheses and then the "MULTIPOLYGON". This seems not very comfortable too me...

Shouldnt it be more like the following? If yes, how can i achieve this kind of output format?

```
{ "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]],
    [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],
     [[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ST_AsText](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) converts to [Well-known text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), while [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) converts to [GeoJSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON). Try:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsGeoJSON(latlon) AS geom FROM district;
```